# Tesseract.js spread syntax (ellipsis) error "Unexpected token ..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract, spread-syntax, tesseract.js

I am trying to use the tesseract.js package in a node app. I am starting with a basic example from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.js):

```
Tesseract = require("tesseract.js");

Tesseract.recognize(
  'https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png',
  'eng',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  console.log(text);
})
```

However, running this app (in Heroku) yields the following error:

```
  /app/node_modules/tesseract.js/src/index.js:24
     ...Tesseract,
    ^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
```

I am trying to resolve this error. There is a "..." in [this index.js file in the package code](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/src/index.js) - any ideas why this would be causing a problem? Not sure if I should submit an "issue" about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh, the problem seems to have been that my Heroku app was using a very outdated version of node, which I found by running

```
heroku run bash
node -v
```

I have updated it and everything works fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which version of node you were running, and what version you needed?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think I got it to work with node 14.x or 16.x.